# Are interactive command lines from orange3 possible

Tags: orange

I wonder whether `orange3` allows to get commands that are running "behind" a certain statistical procedure? This would be like in `R`, when using `RCmdr`.

Comment: Presumingly, you mean this enhancement request: https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/1341